# Trying to export a cloud function using node 8

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function written in JS like so

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions")
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
admin.initializeApp()

// Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

exports.simpleHTTP = functions.http.onRequest((request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!")
})
```

and I am trying to export it in my index.js like so

```
export { simpleHTTP } from "./http"
```

I am running node version 8 and am unsure of how to write the export in the correct way via javascript

Comment: What exactly is the error?  Please edit the question to be clear  Are you actually asking how to do this in JavaScript?  node isn't a programming language.  It's a runtime environment that runs JavaScript or languages that transpile into JavaScript, such as TypeScript.

Comment: Node(JS) carries its own set of syntax as does typescript, I would just like to know the proper syntax for exporting the simpleHTTP cloud function

Comment: node doesn't have "syntax". JavaScript has syntax.  The version of node determines which JS syntax you can use.

Comment: my apologies using node version 8; therefore, unsure of the proper way to export the function

Comment: @DougStevenson any help would be appreciated